# Am I correct that Elasticsearch simple_query_string does not support wildcards, but only prefix queries?

Tags: elasticsearch

There are a number of related questions on stackoverflow, but they mostly suggest other ways to do wildcards. I'm trying to analyze an existing install, so alternatives are not useful.

I think the issue I ran into was that simple_query_string and wildcard queries do different things with infix *.

the query

```
r*g
```

expands to "+msg:r +msg:g" with simple_query_string:

```
GET /test/_validate/query?rewrite=true
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string" : {
        "query": "r*g",
        "fields": ["msg"],
        "default_operator": "AND"
    }
  }
}
```

Returns

```
{
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "valid": true,
  "explanations": [
    {
      "index": "test",
      "valid": true,
      "explanation": "+msg:r +msg:g"
    }
  ]
}
```

Which shows that simple query string is not treading this as a wildcard at all. Not even for r*
So, it will not match "running", for example.

On the other hand, wildcard query does handle infix.

```
GET /test/_validate/query?rewrite=true
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "msg": {
        "value": "r*g",
        "case_insensitive": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

returns

```
{
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "valid": true,
  "explanations": [
    {
      "index": "test",
      "valid": true,
      "explanation": """msg:AutomatonQuery {
org.apache.lucene.util.automaton.Automaton@78b3b2e7}"""
    }
  ]
}
```

While the automaton query could use better output, r*g as a wildcard query will match "running", but a simple_query_string will not.

So, am I correct that the sample query string matches very different sets for simple_query_string vs. wildcard query?

Comment: simple_query_string supports (*) only at end of term (prefix query). You can use query_string for wildcard.  In general wildcard queries are slow. You can also look at n-gra m tokenizer for better performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You are right. `simple_query_string` only support wildcard in end of the query string.

> `*` at the end of a term signifies a prefix query

You can see below line in [documentation](https://You%20can%20see%20below%20the%20line%20%20documentation%20so%20it%20is%20ignored%20*%20in%20your%20scenario.) so it is ignored `*` in your scenario.

> the `simple_query_string query` does not return errors for invalid
> syntax. Instead, it ignores any invalid parts of the query string.

You can use `query_string` of query but it is strict and validate query syntax.

> You can use the query_string query to create a complex search that
> includes wildcard characters, searches across multiple fields, and
> more. While versatile, the query is strict and returns an error if the
> query string includes any invalid syntax.

Comment: Incorrect per https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/opensearch/query-dsl/full-text/#simple-query-string   example clearly show prepended wildcard. However, of note it does not support '?' like index searches

Comment: @BRandall I have put this answer in context of Elasticsearch and not in Opensearch. it may be possible that it is working in opensearch and not in Elasticsearch.